# How can I use Python to convert an adjacency matrix to a transition matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, probability, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to convert a matrix like

```
1 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 1
```

to become

```
1 ⅓ 0 
0 ⅓ ½ 
0 ⅓ ½
```

I was thinking about summing the rows and then dividing by them, but I was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this using numpy or any other way in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `numpy` like below

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 1]])

print(arr/arr.sum(axis=0))
```

```
[[1.0.33333333 0.]
 [0.0.33333333 0.5]
 [0.0.33333333 0.5]]
```